# How to add chat bot v4 avatar icon in web chat?

Tags: javascript, html, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have to add an avatar to bot respons but i don't find the way to do it.

I have tried with the botAvatarInitials and userAvatarInitials [Change the avatar of the bot within the dialog box](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/SAMPLES.md#change-the-avatar-of-the-bot-within-the-dialog-box)
 but it isn't exactly what I want.

```
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: botConnection,
        styleOptions: styleOptions,
        botAvatarInitials: 'BOT',
        userAvatarInitials: 'YOU'
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

There is a way to use an image? Or at least change the avatar bubble color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can set an image by using the `botAvatarImage` property as outlined in [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/b0c803e5722bd8859b5891c6165d55aa8405ed96/samples/04.b.display-user-bot-images-styling/README.md).

It will look something like this:

```
const styleOptions = {
    botAvatarImage: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0',
    botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
    userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64',
    userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: botConnection,
    styleOptions
 }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

To set the background for the avatar bubble you can do the following:

```
const styleOptions = {
    bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
    bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: botConnection,
    styleOptions
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```